# SQL Soccer match exercise - adding columns, details and improved ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

I've recently started practicing SQL, having some prior experience with MySQL only for website db management purposes, but no actual SQL query construction.
Variations of this exercise have been asked before, but I would like to expand the scope of previous solutions.
This is a Football (Soccer) score exercise, constructing a table of aggregate results of different games in a small league.

**TL;DR
I managed to get to a partial solution, but would like to add 3 more columns to the final table, and improve way the final ranking is calculated.**

I created a table of 4 teams and assigned an ID to each one:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams AS
  SELECT 100 AS TEAM_ID, 'PUMP' AS TEAM UNION ALL
  SELECT 200, 'UP' UNION ALL
  SELECT 300, 'THE' UNION ALL
  SELECT 400, 'JAM';
```

For which the output is:

```
SELECT * FROM Teams
```

And a table:

| TEAM_ID | TEAM |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | PUMP |
| 200 | UP |
| 300 | THE |
| 400 | JAM |

I then created a second table, with match scores by game:

```
CREATE TABLE Matches AS
SELECT 1 AS MATCH_ID, 100 AS HomeTeam, 200 AS AwayTeam, 2 AS HomeScore, 0 AS AwayScore UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 300, 400, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 400, 100, 0, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 300, 200, 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 200, 400, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 300, 100, 1, 0;
```

To receive:

| MATCH_ID | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | HomeScore | AwayScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 300 | 400 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 400 | 100 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 300 | 200 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 200 | 400 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 300 | 100 | 1 | 0 |

I was able to create a total score table, displaying the total LEAGUE points each team has, with the following pointing rules:

- Team gets 3 points for a win,
- Team gets 1 point for tie,
- Team gets 0 points for loss

```
WITH cteHomePoints AS (SELECT HomeTeam AS Team,
                              CASE
                                WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 3
                                WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                              END AS Points
                         FROM Matches),
     cteAwayPoints AS (SELECT AwayTeam AS Team,
                               CASE
                                 WHEN AwayScore > HomeScore THEN 3
                                 WHEN AwayScore = HomeScore THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                               END AS Points
                          FROM Matches),
     cteAllPoints AS (SELECT Team, Points FROM cteHomePoints
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT Team, Points FROM cteAwayPoints)
SELECT t.TEAM_ID, t.TEAM, COALESCE(SUM(ap.POINTS), 0) AS TOTAL_POINTS
  FROM Teams t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cteAllPoints ap
    ON ap.TEAM = t.TEAM_ID
  GROUP BY  t.TEAM_ID, t.TEAM
  ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(POINTS), 0) DESC, t.TEAM_ID
```

Resulting in this table:

| TEAM_ID | TEAM | TOTAL_POINTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | PUMP | 6 |
| 200 | UP | 4 |
| 300 | THE | 4 |
| 400 | JAM | 2 |

**However, there are 2 things that I would like to complete:**

1. I would like to add 3 more columns to the final table to show for each team:

- GoalsScored
- GoalsReceived
- Difference (between Scored and Received)

2. Team positions determined by number of points, if tied, position is determined by the better “goal difference”, meaning Goals Scored minus Goals received. This affects final reanking (2nd place and 3rd place would switch positions).

I tried tweaking in several different ways, such as adding

```
     cteHomeScore AS (SELECT HomeTeam AS Team,
                             END AS Scored
                         FROM Matches),
     cteAwayScore AS (SELECT AwayTeam AS Team,
                             END AS Received
                         FROM Matches),                               
     cteAllScored AS (SELECT Team, Scored FROM cteHomeScore
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT Team, Received FROM cteAwayScore),
```

But I can't seem to crack it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You could add the goals scored, received and difference to your existing point determination cte's, then sum it up the same way. After that your can order you're result as desired.

Comment: @Parfait 
_GoalsScored_ is the total goals a team scored in all matches it played (aggregated from HomeScore and AwayScore).  
_GoalsReceived_ is the total goals the team's opponents scored on matches it played (aggregated from HomeScore and AwayScore).  
For example, team PUMP (ID 100), scored 3 goals (GoalsScored=3), and received 1 goal (GoalsReceived=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach:

```
SELECT T.TEAM_ID, T.TEAM, 
        SUM(points) AS Points, 
        SUM(HomeScore) AS 'Goals Scored', 
        SUM(AwayScore) AS 'Goals Received',
        SUM(HomeScore-AwayScore) 'GoalDiff'
 FROM 
Teams T 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT HomeTeam AS Team, HomeScore, AwayScore,
       CASE WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 3
            WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS Points
FROM Matches UNION ALL
SELECT AwayTeam,  AwayScore, HomeScore,
       CASE WHEN AwayScore > HomeScore THEN 3
            WHEN AwayScore = HomeScore THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
FROM Matches) mm
ON T.TEAM_ID=mm.team
GROUP BY T.TEAM_ID, T.TEAM
ORDER BY Points DESC, GoalDiff DESC
```

**Update:** I've switched the order `HomeScore` and `AwayScore` from `HomeScore, AwayScore` to `AwayScore, HomeScore` on the `SELECT` section and `HomeScore > AwayScore` to `AwayScore > HomeScore` on the `CASE` expression of the second query in the `UNION ALL` subquery as a result from a very good observation by [@JanezKuhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6367213/janez-kuhar).

[This is the extended fiddle inclusive of the additional data suggested](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb3d2e1cbeac77f752c871c3f21de213)

Answer (score 0):

Consider self-join (instead of `UNION`) that contain needed aggregations and conditional aggregations. As commented, adjust calculations as needed:

```sql
WITH aggHome AS (
     SELECT HomeTeam AS Team
          , SUM(CASE
                  WHEN HomeScore > AwayScore THEN 3
                  WHEN HomeScore = AwayScore THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END) AS HomeSumPoints
          , SUM(HomeScore) As HomeSumScores
          , SUM(AwayScore) As HomeSumReceived
     FROM Matches
     GROUP BY HomeTeam
),
    aggAway AS (
     SELECT AwayTeam AS Team
          , SUM(CASE
                  WHEN AwayScore > HomeScore THEN 3
                  WHEN AwayScore = HomeScore THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END) AS AwaySumPoints
          , SUM(AwayScore) As AwaySumScores
          , SUM(HomeScore) As AwaySumReceived
     FROM Matches
     GROUP BY AwayTeam
)

SELECT h.Team
     , HomeSumPoints + AwaySumPoints As TotalPoints
     , HomeSumScores + AwaySumScores As GoalsScores
     , HomeSumReceived + AwaySumReceived As GoalsReceived
     , (HomeSumScores + AwaySumScores) - 
       (HomeSumReceived + AwaySumReceived) As Difference
FROM aggHome h
LEFT JOIN aggAway a
  ON h.Team = a.Team
```

<sup>**Note**: If some teams *only* play home games or *only* play away games, replace `INNER JOIN` for MySQL's equivalence of SQL's `FULL OUTER JOIN`.</sup>

Comment: this is great - and much more streamlined.   
I am, however, getting an error _Unknown column 'GoalsScores' in 'field list'_ when running this.  
There is a single team (300) that only plays Home games, is it because of that? Unfortunately FULL OUTER JOIN doesn't seem work with that

Comment: Looks llike something to do with line `GoalsScores - GoalsReceived As Difference`

Comment: MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN` (hence *equivalence*). Search on such solutions. But use `LEFT JOIN` for that one team. I thought MySQL allows use of derived columns. Go ahead and repeat the expression. See edit.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, it seems to do the trick - I tried it before with LEFT JOIN, but it didn't work because of a typo I had, but now it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL which scored 100% by Codility

```
SELECT 
a.team_id,
a.team_name,
(
coalesce ((SELECT 

sum(case when guest_goals > host_goals then 3
     when guest_goals = host_goals then 1
     else 0 end) as guest_points      
from matches where guest_team=a.team_id group by guest_team),0) +
coalesce ((SELECT 
sum(case when host_goals > guest_goals then 3
     when host_goals = guest_goals then 1
     else 0 end) as host_points      
from matches where host_team=a.team_id group by host_team),0) ) as num_points

from teams  a
order by num_points desc,a.team_id
```